# QUERY using cell contents as SQL variables

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

Here is what the spreadsheet I'm working with looks like:

#### Summary table

(top of sheet)

[image: screenshot]

#### Source data

(same sheet, below output)

[image: screenshot]

I'm using the [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343) function to populate the appropriate feeds in the summary table with the data starting at A24 needs to be placed into.

Here is the formula I'm using in cell C6 (similar formulas are used throughout the summary table):

```
=QUERY($A$24:$D$57, "Select D Where B='ENQ' and A='2/27/14 - Thu'")
```

This gets the right information, but the formula needs to be edited to be unique in each cell it's used in. The problem being unable to quickly populate the cells with `A='2/27/14 - Thu'` being too specific.

I was trying to set it up so that:

- date in A would compare with dates found on headers in ROW 2 before accepting data
- room type in B would compare with value from A in each row of the summary table

How can the QUERY function be written to refer to these values as variables, instead of using the literal strings in my original function?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. Instead of fixed strings such as `'ENQ'`, you can have your formula refer to the index in column A of your output. For example, you could change your formula to this, in cell C4:

   ```
   =QUERY($A$24:$D, "Select D Where B='" & $A4 & "' and A='2/27/14 - Thu'")
                                            ^^^^^^^
   ```

   The ampersand (`&`) is used to concatenate string segments.

   Note that since the source data extends to the bottom of the data range of the sheet, we can forego specifying the bottom row. The range `$A$24:$D` will take in all rows, so it will automatically adjust to additional source data.
2. To compare dates, both values need to be dates. "2/27/14 - Thu" is not recognized as a date in your source data sheet, but as text, even though you've set the numeric format to date. So make sure you change all your source data to have actual dates in column A.

   You can still have your dates formatted the way you like - see this screenshot. The content of A2 is now a proper date, "2/27/2014", but the format is set to display "mm/dd/yy - DDD". As long as the *data* is a date, the query can be built using the spreadsheet `TEXT` function to interpret the date in its yyyy-mm-dd format.

   [image: screenshot]
3. With dates in your source column, you can use `todate()` scalar function to tell `QUERY` to convert the date in the source to a query-date, and the `date` keyword to treat the following literal string (from C2) as a date.

   The resulting function for cell C4 is:

   ```
   =QUERY($A$24:$D , "Select D Where B='" & $A4 & "'and todate(A) = date '" & TEXT($C$2,"yyyy-MM-dd") & "'")
                                                           ^^^^^^      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ```

   Similarly, for D4:

   ```
   =QUERY($A$24:$D , "Select C Where B='"&$A4&"'and todate(A) = date '"&TEXT($C$2,"yyyy-MM-dd")&"'")
   ```
4. Your calculations in column E can be improved to handle `#N/A` results appearing in columns C or D:

   ```
   =if(isna(C12*D12),0,C12*D12)
   ```

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much for your help! I can't Thumbs up you unfortunately.

For you to actually do the work for me is insanely great of you!!

Comment: No problem, @Jimmy! I've updated the question to include all the relevant info and to be useful for more people. You can remove the link to your spreadsheet & remove the sharing, if you want.

Comment: Hi Mogsdad! One last thing... How did you efficiently turn the date cells into dates? It won't click into date format for me until I delete the "- Thu". I've tried messing around with the custom date formulas etc. that you've suggested. Thanks!

Comment: I did just that - deleted "- Thu". Then copied & pasted to other rows with the same date, then edited the next, rinse, repeat. If you have hundreds of these things, you could fill a temporary column with `=datevalue(LEFT(A3,(find("-",A3)-1)))` and then copy the resulting date values back over the original column. (That formula is for row 3, btw.)