# How to compare a DATE with a TEXT string in a QUERY function in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-query-language

Goal: Return a specific value from a table of data based on a query (kinda like if VLOOKUP provided the option for multiple criteria).

Problem: The data in the source table is a value and I can't change the data source's format. When I run my QUERY function I get `#N/A`. I know it's due to the data type of the source table data because when I update the format to "plain text" the value works.

Here is my Query:

```
=QUERY(SessionsData,"select D where B='"&TEXT(Date(YEAR(TODAY()),4,$A143),"yyyy-MM-dd")&"' limit 1",0)
```

I know the logic works, watch [this video for a brief demo](https://docs.google.com/a/argyleanalytics.net/file/d/0B5UBYi--aG5NQXF5WTE3QjZIS2c/edit).

How can I get this comparison to return results?

Comment: Hi Kevin, can you share a copy of your spreadsheet ? That would make things a lot easier.

Answer (score 3):

Adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26457935/1677912):

The Query language has two functions to help with date comparisons.

- The `todate()` scalar function will convert spreadsheet dates (like your column `B`) to query date values. If the value started as a datetime, it returns just the date portion.
- The `date` modifier treats *specifically formatted* strings as query date values.

Use them like so:

```
=QUERY(SessionsData,"select D where todate(B)=date '"&TEXT(Date(YEAR(TODAY()),4,$A143),"yyyy-MM-dd")&"' limit 1",0)
                                    ^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^
```